# results side by side instead of each other

Tags: sql

i would like to have my results side by side instead of each other

[image: current]

[image: should]

My query is

```
select  MONTH(begin_ts) as Monate,
SUM(dauer) as dauer, m_status as Störung
from [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_ereignis]
WHERE masch_nr IN('FIMI1')
AND m_status IN('50','60')
AND YEAR(begin_ts)='2020'
GROUP BY m_status,masch_nr, MONTH(begin_ts)
```

I hope you can help.

Many thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT  MONTH(begin_ts) as Monate,
        SUM(CASE WHEN m_status = '50' THEN dauer END) as dauer_50, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN m_status = '60' THEN dauer END) as dauer_60
FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_ereignis]
WHERE masch_nr IN ('FIMI1') AND
      m_status IN ('50', '60') AND
      YEAR(begin_ts) = 2020
GROUP BY MONTH(begin_ts);
```

Notes:

- If `m_status` is a number, drop the single quotes.  Avoid mixing data types (strings and numbers) in expressions.
- I know of no database where `YEAR()` returns a string.  The comparison should be to a number.
- I would recommend `begin_ts` >= '2020-01-01' and begin_ts < '2021-01-01'` to get data from one year.